# Saving file properties results in Value does not fall in range exception

Tags: c#, uwp

I have the following code that is supposed to retrieve a canvas, save an image, and then write File properties to it. Sadly, it crashes when trying to save the properties. They are in string form, and the Property requires a string too, so I don't see what might be wrong:

```
try
{
    using (Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream stream =
            await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
    {
        stream.Size = 0;
        await MyInkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.SaveAsync(stream);
    }

    ImageProperties imageProperties = await file.Properties.GetImagePropertiesAsync();
    string title = CanvasGrid.Width + " x " + CanvasGrid.Height;
    imageProperties.Title = title;
    await imageProperties.SavePropertiesAsync();

    //MainPage.NotifyUser("File has been saved!", NotifyType.StatusMessage);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //MainPage.NotifyUser(ex.Message, NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
}
```

> Value does not fall within the expected range.

Comment: Which line throws that error?

Comment: @when saving, so await imageProperties.SavePropertiesAsync();